# is_page_template not working as expected

Tags: custom-post-types, php, templates, page-template, conditional-tags

I'm trying to serve different headers based on what type of page the user is on. This is my code.

```
<!-- IF HOME -->
        <?php if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/headers/home-header' ); ?> 

        <!-- IF TEMPLATES -->

        <?php elseif ( is_page_template('archive-mobile_photo.php') ) : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/headers/home-header' ); ?> 

        <!-- IF  POST -->
        <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/headers/zine-header' ); ?>     

        <?php endif; ?>
```

What's weird is that the homepage and post pages are working fine, but the check using `is_page_template()` isn't working. I have the query monitor plugin and it's confirming the page is the `archive-mobile_photo.php` template.

I'm pretty new to WordPress and I'm at a total loss.

Comment: Where is the template file located in the theme directory ?

Comment: It's in the same directory as the the file I'm working in. I kept checking to make sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're checking if you're on the `mobile_photo` post type archive with this line:

```
<?php elseif ( is_page_template( 'archive-mobile_photo.php' ) ) : ?>
```

If that's indeed the case, use [`is_post_type_archive( $post_types )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive) instead:

```
<?php elseif ( is_post_type_archive( 'mobile_photo' ) ) : ?>
```

Comment: Bless you kind sir! How would I have come to this? Just read the documentation until I've tried everything? I should probably do that. Thanks!!

Comment: You got it! I didn't see the problem at first glance, but the details in your question (thank you for that) pointed me to `is_page_template()`. I recognized the pattern being used as `archive-{post_type}.php` from the ever-important [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), and thought we may have had a winner.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the conditionals to load headers as template parts, it would be more readable to use the functionality built in to `get_header()` when you call it for each page template. These files would live in the root of the theme folder.

You would name your two files `header-home.php` and `header-zine.php` and call them in the page template with:

`get_header('home');`

and

`get_header('zine');`

If you do need the conditionals for a more complex page, you can still check the page and load the appropriate file based on your criteria. There's an [example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) of that in the codex as well.

I'm not sure what the difference is between `get_header()` and `get_template_part()` but if nothing else, I think it's more readable, and follows the WordPress standard.